# I want to capture document of Safari in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to get a image of web page from Safari not Safari application screenshot.

I try to capture this by CGWindowImageList? function but this function capture application screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try and load up the page in a `UIWebView` and drawing the view onto a buffer unless you specifically need to capture a running Safari session. This is what [Paparazzi](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/) does, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I don't want to reload the page. I want to capture current session. is there any other solution?